# crash log debugging

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, uitableview, crash-reports

one of my app user is getting a wearied crash and he send me the report can any one help me in finding the error. The app is already in use so needed to fix it soon.

He said that he is getting the crash when he is navigating in a particular parten. its not happening when in general but if we go in a particular manner the its crashing.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x65436572
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3388f5b6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   UIKit                           0x3a380ecc __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke_0 + 220
2   UIKit                           0x3a1d209e +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 70
3   UIKit                           0x3a1d2050 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 96
4   UIKit                           0x3a1cf558 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 432
5   UIKit                           0x3a1b4306 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1306
6   UIKit                           0x3a1cb7c2 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 202
7   UIKit                           0x3a1877fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
8   QuartzCore                      0x397b2d5e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
9   QuartzCore                      0x397b28fc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
10  QuartzCore                      0x397b3830 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
11  QuartzCore                      0x397b3216 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
12  QuartzCore                      0x397b3024 CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
13  UIKit                           0x3a18d8e6 _afterCACommitHandler + 122
14  CoreFoundation                  0x329ab6ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
15  CoreFoundation                  0x329a99bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
16  CoreFoundation                  0x329a9d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3291ceb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3291cd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
19  GraphicsServices                0x3a71a2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
20  UIKit                           0x3a1d82f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
21  APP                             0x00103f64 main (main.m:15)
22  APP                             0x000fe88c start + 36

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bc4d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350048a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb4648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34fd54ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34fc7df4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bc4d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350048a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb3eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb4048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x329ab040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x329a9d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3291ceb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3291cd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x36c78a40 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb3eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb4048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x329ab040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x329a9d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3291ceb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3291cd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x3451378a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x345b7058 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   APP                             0x0013ee96 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:127)
9   Foundation                      0x345c0678 __NSThread__main__ + 968
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f30e _pthread_start + 306
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb3eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bb4048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x329ab040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x329a9d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3291ceb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3291cd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x3453cbc8 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x345c0678 __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bc4594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x329af1f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f30e _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500f1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bc4d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350048a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bc4d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350048a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31bc4d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35004a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350048a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x2fd029f0    r1: 0x3a60c4ec      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x6543657a
    r4: 0x3a60dbc7    r5: 0x00000001      r6: 0x3a60109d      r7: 0x2fd029b0
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x0e98313b     r10: 0x000002f4     r11: 0x2fd029d0
    ip: 0x3c399d64    sp: 0x2fd02908      lr: 0x3a380ed1      pc: 0x3388f5b6
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

Comment: Hi folks,  i have fixed the problem. after lots of research and R&D i finally did it. the cell in the code was getting nil and was returning null, beacuse the data was downloading so many times and it was clearing the dataarray which eventually making the cell to go nil and crash. sorry for this silly mistake.

Comment: thanks to all who tried to help me out. Amir Bareket specially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are using multiThreading for network operations.
in case you calling your thread from UIViewContoller please look at the Deallocation problem:
[deallocation problem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2109/_index.html)

search for the paragraph deallocation problem.
thats happens when calling threads from UIViewControoler and navigating before thread finish works.

look at the link for full description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Document, but i am not able to decode the error.

Comment: please share more details about your app otherwise it could be difficult to answer only from this log  . do you call background thread from UIViewController ?